# Laravel crash after adding a raw

Tags: laravel, crash

[image]

Im displaying a treeview data and everything works perfecly. 
But when i add the **fourth** raw, Laravel crash.

I want to post my code but i don't even know which one and where that came from..

[image]
view :

```
<div class="list-group">
                 <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="col-md-2">Departement</div>

                            <div class=" float-right">
                               <button class=" btn-primary" type="button" data-toggle="collapse"    data-target=".multi-collapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="multiCollapseExample1" >
                                   <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span></button>
                              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning "  data-toggle="modal"  data-target="#exampleModalposition"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></span></button> </div> 
                            </div>
                                <div class="list-group-item" name="state">

                      @foreach($treeViewPosition as $departement)
                                     <div  class=" collapse multi-collapse collapse in " id="8"  >         
                       <div class="col-md-2"> {{ $departement->departement_name}}</div>
                       <div class=" float-right"><button class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="collapse"   data-target="#{{ $departement->id}}8" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="{{ $departement->id}}8">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span></button></div>
         <div class="list-group">
  @if(count($departement->position))
          @include('treeposition2',['position'=>$departement->position])
       @endif
            </div>
     @endforeach
   </div>
   </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: what do you mean crash ? inspect element and show us the errors

Comment: Hello sir. Seems the error comes from vue.js. but there is no error message. Pplease check out my eddited post

Comment: are you using vue.js or jquery and ajax when adding items ?

Comment: I'm using Vue.js sir